# iTunes Connect old version of app

Tags: ios, itunesconnect

Apple now lets devs manage availability of app's previous versions in the rights and pricing module section.

I can't see it.

Can anyone else?

Comment: Since it's made only to show the last compatible version for the user (for iOS version). Maybe this view is not available if there are no compatibilities differences between your current version and the first version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a bit hidden, go to the "Rights and Pricing" of your app, there select the "Indicate a legal issue with iCloud for this app".

Now you will be able to select which version of the app will not be available from iCloud backup. This also affects the "Install previous version".

[image]

Comment: Ah ha, I almost clicked that earlier as well but assumed it wasn't in there. So this is only for users who have already purchased the app? (as it's an iCloud download/restore)

Comment: It's now been changed to "Manage iCloud download settings for this app", but the list looks the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

Let me credit @grgarside for his answer here -> https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254181/121124

**iTunes Connect → My Apps → app → App Store → Pricing & Availability → Last-Compatible Version Settings → Available Versions.**

is the new flow sequence, you are looking for.
I am writing this as a new answer, as the user interface has changed a lot as compared to the 2013 version.

here is the 2017 version

[image: itunesconnect last-compatible version settings]